# Create a zip file from a list of selected files and make the zipped file downloadable in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, files

How to create zip file programatically based on the files selected in Drupal 8? Is there any class already existing in Drupal 8?

As per below answer I'm using following code to generate zip file:

```
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fileId);
$fileUri = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri());

$zip = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.archiver')->getInstance(['f‌​ilepath' => '/foo/bar.zip']);
$zip->add($fileUri);
```

- The bar.zip file above should exist in the referenced path above: `/foo/bar.zip`.
- Also how do I flatten the the zip file folder structure so that the file `sites/default/files/myimage.png` is `myimage.png`?

Comment: Yes. Archiver has existed since Drupal 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [ArchiverManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21ArchiverManager.php/class/ArchiverManager/8.3.x) and get the instance by calling the `getInstance()` method. A [Zip](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21Zip.php/class/Zip/8.3.x) class is returned. The Drupal `Zip` class uses PHP's [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to perform the heavy lifting.

**Example (edited after remark @Clive):**

```
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fileId);
$fileUri = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri());

$zip = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.archiver')->getInstance(['f‌​ilepath' => '/foo/bar.zip']);
$zip->add($fileUri);
```

Comment: Don't instantiate the object manually, always use services for this type of thing. `$zip = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.archiver')->getInstance(['filepath' => '/foo/bar.zip']);` (and preferably inject the service if in a viable context too)

Comment: Thanks a lot Clive! Did not realize that it had a service. Updated my answer for future reference.

Comment: I tried your method mentioned above. But when run the code the 'bar.zip' file should exist in the mentioned the path. Also for the given fid the file adding to the zip file by including all the folder structure.. Inside zip file having following folder structure 'sites/defualt/files/myimage.png'. I only want that file alone inside zip file. Not all the file path folders.

Comment: @Gun5m0k3, have any idea on my above comment?

Comment: I am afraid that the Drupal `Zip` class does not provide methods to use a local name. The `add()` method calls the PHP `ZipArchive` method `addFile()` with only the first parameter. I guess that you have to create a `ZipArchive` instance yourself (instead of using the `plugin.manager.archiver` service) and call the `addFile()` method with the full file path and the local file name: `$zip->addFile('full/path/to/myimage.png', 'myimage.png')`.

Comment: Just found the `getArchive()` method on the `Zip` class. So I would use the `plugin.manager.archiver` service, retrieve the PHP `ZipArchive` class by calling `$zip->getArchive()` and call the `addFile()` method on that. This way you are still using services which is better practice.

Comment: Yep!!! I already tried that...It worked.. Thank you.

Comment: For me, once you get the ZipArchive class, you can AddFile(). Once you have finished addFile() on each File entity it was only then this class made the close() method available. Now we're cooking, because without that method my zip file was always 0 bytes and unfinished.

Answer (score 1):

Below sample code is working fine to create zip file in Drupal 8.

```
$file = File::load($file_id);
$filename = $file->getFilename();
$file_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri());
$destination = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('public://foldername');
$zip = new \ZipArchive;
$zip->open($destination . "\dump.zip", constant("ZipArchive::CREATE"));
$zip->addFile($file_path, $filename);
$zip->close();
```

Please check [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module soruce code for more reference.

Note :

1. Create the destination folder before execute this above code.
2. Please make sure php zip and gd libraries should be installed and enabled
   in the server.
3. Recommended to use external zip creation library when the server doesn't support **zipArchive** class.